# Use of GIS in fixed telecommunication network management

Tags: references

I want to get an idea how GIS can be used in fixed line telecommunication management?
there are open source GIS tools as well as Proprietary tools as well.
what is the best tool can be used in above ?

Answer (score 1):

There was a recent Poll on Linked-In, very similar to this - "What is the best GIS package to use for Fixed Telecoms Network Planning?".  It rated of number of GIS systems, one which was mentioned was Telcordia's Network Engineer (based on ESRI's ArcGIS) which is ideally suited for this (http://www.telcordia.com/products/network_eng/index.html).